Conditionally mutating 2 dataframes
I have two data frames: df1 and df2.
df1:



Time
ID
Place_Holder




13:10:00
#1
g


13:10:00
#2
g


14:10:00
#1
g


14:10:00
#2
g


15:50:00
#1
g



df2:



Start_Time
End_Time
Info




13:00:00
13:55:00
abc


14:00:00
14:30:00
xyz


15:00:00
15:20:00
tuv



How can I efficiently mutate data from the 'Info' column in df2 to df1, given that 'Time' in df1 is between 'Start_Time' and 'End_Time' in df2?
Here is the expected output:



Time
ID
Info




13:10:00
#1
abc


13:10:00
#2
abc


14:10:00
#1
xyz


14:10:00
#2
xyz



Additional Information:
ID #1 and #2 data are taken at the same time. If a 'Time' value does not fall within any 'Start_Time' 'End_Time' range, then that row should be removed in the final output (for example, the 15:50:00 'Time' did not fall within any time range specified in df2 and is therefor excluded in the final output).
The "Place_Holder" column in df1 is just a place holder to mutate the info column onto as you will see in the code I have tried.
I have tried the following code:
for (i in df1$Time) {
  for (q in c(1:3)) {
    if (between(i,df2$Start_Time[q],df2$End_Time[q])) {
      df1$Place_Holder[i] <- df2$Info[q]
      break
    } 
  }
}

I am sure this code will work if I had a quantum computer, but I don't. With the big data set I am working with, I need to use more efficient code to do this.
I also saw suggestions on Stack Overflow of using the map2 function from the purrr package along with case_when(), but I will have to be able to then iterate through 3 vectors (df1$Time, df2$Start_Time, df2$End_Time). The map 2 function only allows for 2 vectors as input. Is there a function that can take more than two vector inputs to d this?
Side question: When working with case_when(), why can't I use the following code case_when(between(x = df1$Time, lower = df2$Start_Time, upper = df2$End_Time))?

Check the relatively new helpers in dplyr's join functions, particularly the "overlapping joins" that can be defined via join_by: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html

And please include outputs from dput(df1) and dput(df2) to provide example datasets for others,  we can guess but don't really know whats behind string representations of those time values in your frames,  with dput() you can provide reproducible datasets.

Here's an approach using inner_join with between (basically what @deschen suggested in the comments)
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, join_by(between(Time, Start_Time, End_Time))) %>%
  select(Time, ID, Info)
      Time ID Info
1 13:10:00 #1  abc
2 13:10:00 #2  abc
3 14:10:00 #1  xyz
4 14:10:00 #2  xyz


Interesting that the join also works without converting the character to a "time" object. Not sure if it would always work or if there might be cases where the automatic translation might fail.

@deschen Yep, I think it will never fail (haven't tested different locales though). It will almost always be more safe to convert to Time but as a test sort(c("12:45:34","11:23:12","12:45:33")) will always sort correctly.

Here's to R's smartness.

@deschen Love R :) but to be fair, I think it also works in almost all languages that have an ASCII table and sort (just tested with ruby and Julia).

Here's a tidyverse approach (taking teh example data from Rui Barradas):
library(tidyverse)

df1 |> 
  mutate(Time_join = as_datetime(Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")) |> 
  inner_join(df2 |> 
               mutate(Start_Time = as_datetime(Start_Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
                      End_Time   = as_datetime(End_Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")),
             join_by(between(Time_join, Start_Time, End_Time))) |> 
  select(-Start_Time, -End_Time, -Time_join)

      Time ID Place_Holder Info
1 13:10:00 #1            g  abc
2 13:10:00 #2            g  abc
3 14:10:00 #1            g  xyz
4 14:10:00 #2            g  xyz


With package sqldf it's a matter of joining with between.
library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite

sql <- "
select Time, Start_Time, End_Time, Info
  from df1, df2
  where Time between Start_Time and End_Time
"
sqldf(sql) |> merge(df1) -> result
result[!duplicated(result[c("Time", "ID")]), c(1, 5, 4)]
#>       Time ID Info
#> 1 13:10:00 #1  abc
#> 2 13:10:00 #2  abc
#> 5 14:10:00 #1  xyz
#> 6 14:10:00 #2  xyz

Created on 2024-09-30 with reprex v2.1.0

Note
The times columns are of class "character". You can coerce the times to real times with package chron.
library(chron)

df1$Time <- times(df1$Time)
df2$Start_Time <- times(df2$Start_Time)
df2$End_Time <- times(df2$End_Time)

Data
df1 <-
structure(list(Time = c("13:10:00", "13:10:00", "14:10:00", "14:10:00", 
"15:50:00"), ID = c("#1", "#2", "#1", "#2", "#1"), Place_Holder = c("g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <-
structure(list(Start_Time = c("13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00"), 
End_Time = c("13:55:00", "14:30:00", "15:20:00"), Info = c("abc", 
"xyz", "tuv")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

